# Dotmim.Sync is throwing exception when synchronizing existing SQLite with SQL Server databases

Tags: sql-server, sqlite, .net-standard

I get a `Dotmim.Sync.SyncException` when calling the `agent.SynchronizeAsync(tables)` function:

> Exception: Seems you are trying another Setup tables that what is stored in your server scope database. Please make a migration or create a new scope

This is my code:

```
public static async Task SynchronizeAsync()
{
    var serverProvider = new SqlSyncProvider(serverConnectionString);

    // Second provider is using plain old Sql Server provider, relying on triggers and tracking tables to create the sync environment
    var clientProvider = new SqliteSyncProvider(Path.Combine(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, "treesDB.db3"));

    // Tables involved in the sync process:
    var tables = new string[] { "Trees" };

    // Creating an agent that will handle all the process
    var agent = new SyncAgent(clientProvider, serverProvider);

    // Launch the sync process
    var s1 = await agent.SynchronizeAsync(tables);

    await agent.LocalOrchestrator.UpdateUntrackedRowsAsync();

    var s2 = await agent.SynchronizeAsync();
}
```

Comment: Nothing in this code is specific to Maui. I've edited the title and tags correspondingly. (StackOverflow does not yet have a "dotmim.sync" tag.) The exception seems to be specific to [Dotmim.Sync](https://dotmimsync.readthedocs.io/) - you might need to add an issue at their github, to get help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm the author of Dotmim.Sync
Do not hesitate to to fill an issue on Github if you are still struggling.

Regarding your issue, I think you have made some tests with different tables.
You need to stick with a set of tables, because DMS needs to create different things (triggers / stored proc and so on)

If you want to test different setups, you need to define differents scopes.
You have a complete documentation on https://dotmimsync.readthedocs.io/